# DecimalFormat parsing BigInteger loses scale

Tags: java, android

`new BigDecimal("1.00")` correctly produces a `BigDecimal` with a scale of 2.  However, if you do this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(Locale.US);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) df.parse("1.00", new ParsePosition(0));
```

...`bd` will have a scale of 0.  I'm doing it this way because the `BigDecimal` constructor can't handle strings with grouping separators, e.g., `"1,234.56"`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?  I'm seeing this behavior with Android SDK 19.

Edit: created [issue #75581](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75581).

Comment: Are you sure?  (http://ideone.com/jXHIcJ)  If you're genuinely seeing this behaviour with your SDK, then it sounds like an implementation bug.

Comment: Yep.  Maybe it's Android-specific.